# forEach loop, adding a class to each item but with an increasing delay to each

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I'm attempting to create an animated effect for a group of elements and have successfully created the effect in jquery but i'm trying to learn vanilla javascript and wanted some help translating what I already have:

```
<div id="vertical-lines">
  <span class="one item"></span>
  <span class="two item"></span>
  <span class="three item"></span>
  <span class="four item"></span>
  <span class="five item"></span>
</div>
```

This is the jquery that works fine.

```
$('.item').each(function(i){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.item').eq(i).addClass('is-visible');
  }, 200 * i);
});
```

This is what I've been trying but keep coming back with undefined from the [i]

```
var lineItem = document.querySelectorAll('.item'), i
lineItem.forEach(i => {
  setTimeout(function(i){
    console.log(lineItem[i])
    // lineItem[i].className  += "otherclass"
  }, 20)
});
```

I would appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong! I'm new to javascript but love it so far and want to know more and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: In `Array.prototype.forEach()` the first argument is the reference to the current node, index is the second variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In`Array.prototype.forEach()` three arguments are supplied automatically (and in order):

1. Reference to the current Array element,
2. The index of the current Array element,
3. A reference to the whole array.

I'd suggest rewriting your approach as follows:

```
var lineItem = Array.from (document.querySelectorAll('.item'))
lineItem.forEach((arrayElement, index) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(lineItem[index]);
    lineItem[index].className  += " otherclass";
 }, 20);
});
```

Further I'd suggest that, instead of manipulating the string returned by `Element.className` you should take advantage of the `Element.classList.add('otherclass');` method.

Comment: Thank you this works great and I think I understand how it's all set up :) appreciate the help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The closure you are using with `setTimeout` has a parameter of `i` which will be undefined. `setTimeout` does not pass any parameters to the closure.

`.forEach()` passes the current element as the first parameter, and the index as the second parameter.

In order to increase the delay by 20ms for each item, you should use the following formula: `20 * (index + 1)`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var lineItem = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
lineItem.forEach((item, index) => { // Add item to closure
  setTimeout(() => { // Removed i from closure
    console.log(item) // Console logging item. Could use lineItem[index] instead
    item.className  += "otherclass"
  }, 20 * (index + 1)) // Increase the delay time by 20ms for each item
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of ForEach, why don't you use a recursive call ?

```
var lineItem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')], i = 0;
function delayIt(arr, i) {
    var item = arr.shift();
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log(item); 
      arr.length && delayIt(arr, i);
    }, 20 * ++i)
}
delayIt(lineItem, i)
```

Comment: Seeing `forEach` works and it is what OP is using you going to have to elaborate a little more than `don't use forEach`. Why not? What exactly did you change and why does it fix the issue?

Comment: I don't really like `.shift()` here either, as it will manipulate the lineItem array. And the `.shift()` is what ends the loop by making `arr.length` become false when the array is empty. So you rely on the side effect of the 'loop' to actually make the code work, which is very unintuitive for people trying to learn how to program and outright prohibited if you use fucntional programming in js. So for me this is a textbook example of writing clever code just for the sake of being clever.

Comment: You guys are right, I change my sentence according to your remarks